# Does tensorflow handle swapping GPU memory when a model exceeds memory capacity?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've noticed that a recent model warns that 2.37G of memory wasn't able to be allocated:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.37GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
```

But my GPU is operating at nearly 100% (small input compared to a large model in this case).

If I am reading this correctly, I assume that my model did not fit entirely in GPU memory. However since the GPU is running at 100% am I also to assume that tensorflow is intelligently swapping graph elements in and out of GPU memory asynchronously?

I'm just curious to know what's going on under the hood there.

Comment: Functional ops like `while_loop` allows swapping GPU memory to CPU, search for `swap_memory` on github. I'm not aware of any memory swapping happening when you don't use functional ops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know what is going on under the hood add this code to your run function:

```
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
sess = tf.Session(config=config) 
sess.run(train_step,
           feed_dict={x: batch_xs,
                      y_: batch_ys},
            options=tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE),
           run_metadata=run_metadata)
trace = timeline.Timeline(step_stats=run_metadata.step_stats)
with open('timeline.ctf.json', 'w') as trace_file:
   trace_file.write(trace.generate_chrome_trace_format())
```

and then open the generated timeline.ctf.json from the `chrome://timeline` interface and you will see what is going on under the hood.

It is very likely that is swapping GPU memory.